# Scripting which image is active in Single Image Paint mode?

Tags: python, scripting, image, texture-painting

i'm doing some scripting with the texture paint mode, basically calling `bpy.ops.paint.project_image` on multiple layers. It's working fine, except I can't figure out how to switch the image that gets painted in Single Layer mode.

[image: Screenshot of Single Image texture slot]

For example, here I want to apply paint to "Mask" and then switch it to a different image from script and apply paint to that.

How do I change what image this Texture Slot is set to from script?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. It was `image_paint.canvas`, as in:

`bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.image_paint.canvas = bpy.data.images["ImageName", None]`